# Second variable not evaluated

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

In my `create.js.erb` I have this:

```
id = <%= @testitemlog.id -%>;
alert(id);
result = <%= @testitemlog.result -%>;
alert(result);
```

The first alert is shown, the second not, something goes wrong with the 3rd line, but what? The content of `@testitemlog.result` is `Failed` (a string value).

Comment: Can you please elaborate more on this ?

Comment: Show error message from console.

Comment: Have you confirmed that `@testitemlog.result` definitely holds what you expect?

Comment: Yep, it holds the correct value and the console shows nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap `<%= @testitemlog.result %>` with quotes.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  id = <%= @testitemlog.id %>;
  alert(id);
  result = "<%= @testitemlog.result %>";
  alert(result);
</script>
```

If you do not do that, the JavaScript code looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  id = 123;
  alert(id);
  result = Failed;
  alert(result);
</script>
```

and you probably get `Uncaught ReferenceError: Failed is not defined` error in the console.